# How to call VSTO-code from VBA

Tags: vba, wcf, vsto

Given is the following scenario: A .net-class-library with business logic and Excel 2010 Add-In (VSTO) to make it available for users. All is working fine. Now, we need to call some of the logic from VBA. Just something like addLog("no issue") or getString("for ID").

(I know, standard solution is: creating a COM-visible dll and reference it within the VBA-project. However this wouldn't work in the current environment because of missing admin-credentials.)

Now, I am searching a way to make this happen. What I found is:

- **DDE** - but everyone is screaming that it is really outdated
- **WCF-Service hosted within the VSTO Add-In** - but I couldn't find any example that fits vaguely

So, do you have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2009/11/05/interop-between-vba-and-visual-studio-office-solutions-vsto/

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386306.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hekt07s.aspx

Comment: I found the [answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx) in the comments of the first article.

Many many thanks!